# Merge/concatenate/Append dataframe pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes that look like this:

df1:

```
 Index var1
 0      56
 1      67
 2      21

 Index var2
 0      89
 1      64
 2      31
```

When I append or concatenate them, I get this:

```
 Index var1 var2
 0      56  nan
 1      67  nan
 2      21  nan
 0      nan  89
 1      nan  64
 2      nan  31
```

But I would like to get this:

```
 Index var1 var2
 0      56  89
 1      67  64
 2      21  31
```

The commands I used are:

```
 pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
 df1.append([df2])
```

EDIT:

This is a min-example:

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame({'var1' : [56,67,21]})
 df2 = pd.DataFrame({'var2' : [89,64,31]})

 df1.to_dict()
 {'var1': {0: 56, 1: 67, 2: 21}}
 df2.to_dict() 
 {'var2': {0: 89, 1: 64, 2: 31}}

 df1.index.dtype
 dtype('int64')
 df2.index.dtype
 dtype('int64')
```

Comment: Do you need `df1.join(df2)` ?

Comment: I tried that, which creates the shape that I want, so they are next to each other however, the 2nd dataframe is all Nan

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('Index')
df2 = df2.set_index('Index')
pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
```

***NOTE:*** Besure that Index is in the index of the dataframe:

Output:

```
       var1  var2
Index            
0        56    89
1        67    64
2        21    31
```

Comment: so Index is actually my index already and is not a variable in both of them. So when I run: df1 = df1.set_index('Index') I get: KeyError: 'Index'

Comment: Please tell me what df1.to_dict() and df2.to_dict() returns?

Comment: Oh... I just had a thought.  Are the dtypes of both index the same.... df1.index.dtype and df2.index.dtype.  Do the match?

Comment: I have added the output above

Comment: Okay with your giving example `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)` works.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I just tried that. So something else is different then with my actual data.

Comment: Let me investigate, I'll report back.

Comment: Another problem if your indexes are object dtype (strings) then look for whitespace.  Again to_dict() is useful in troubleshooting this data issue.

Comment: So embarrassingly enough for me, it somehow works now, I need retrace my steps to see what exactly caused the error. Thanks for the helpful analysis tools, to_dict() is going into my cheat sheet.

Comment: @NiccolaTartaglia I am glad you found your error.  Happy coding!